# Joomla Blog view, Edit print & email dropdown

Tags: joomla, overriding

I've been changing the way the print & emails funktion in joomla works. By default it is a drop-down located top right of each article.
What I've been doing is changing it to view stand alone icons instead as a drop down.

I've successfully managed to change the print & email drop-down to stand alone icons for article view and featured view, but not for the blog view cause I haven't found the code's location for it's print & email drop-down.

**So my question is:** *Where to edit the print & email drop-down for the blog view?*

Have checked the blog files within in /components/com_content/views/category/tmpl. But can't find the print & email drop-down code in them.

How I've changed it e.g. for the article view .../templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php

I changed the print & email code at line 65 from this:

```
<?php if (!$this->print) : ?>
   <?php if ($canEdit || $params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
   <div class="btn-group pull-right">
   <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <span class="icon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span> </a>
   <?php // Note the actions class is deprecated. Use dropdown-menu instead. ?>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu actions">
      <?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon')) : ?>
      <li class="print-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
      <li class="email-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
      <li class="edit-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
   </ul>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php if (!$this->print) : ?>
   <?php if ($canEdit || $params->get('show_print_icon') || $params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
      <div class="pull-right">
                <?php if ($params->get('show_print_icon')) : ?>
      <li class="print-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.print_popup', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($params->get('show_email_icon')) : ?>
      <li class="email-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.email', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if ($canEdit) : ?>
      <li class="edit-icon"> <?php echo JHtml::_('icon.edit', $this->item, $params); ?> </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I did the same for the featured view. But I can't find the location for where the print & email drop-down code for the blog view is located, been checking pretty much all the files within com_content. But get the feeling that it is located somewhere else?

As of now, every time I enter a blog page on my site I get the drop-down, where as I have the print & email icon displayed as stand alone icons anywhere else on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code you're looking for is in the following file:

```
layouts/joomla/content/icons.php
```

Please note you should not edit this file. Instead you should create an override for it by copying the file to:

```
templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/content
```

If this path doesn't exist, simply create it and put the *icons.php* file inside the *content* folder. You can then start editing it according to your needs.

Hope this helps